# TinyMCE on WordPress misbehaves on client's computer

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have a client who's having trouble with Visual Editor on WordPress but I cannot, for the life of me, replicate the issue my client's having.

A little background...

- For styling purposes, there are certain elements on the content area
  with custom codes/data attributes hard-coded in Text editor by me. I
  primarily work with Foundation framework (by Zurb) and if you're not
  familiar, in the markup there are html attributes like 'data-tabs' or
  'data-accordions' that enable certain stylistic components on the
  front-end.
- I also put a lot of effort in accessibility so there are
  many instances where I add ARIA attributes wherever necessary.
- My client deals with some educational analytical data, so there are some iframes embedded in the content area.

Problem arises when **my client tries to edit text contents in the Visual Editor and the editor strips any custom code I put in, data attributes and outright deletes iframe altogether**.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Even before handing off the project monthes ago, I had added 'valid_elements',
  'extended_valid_elements' rule set in the WordPress filter 'tiny_mce_before_init' to allow any kind of attributes/data sets I want
- Ever since the issue has been reported, I added ARIA attribute specifically just to make sure that it's not being removed
- For iframes being removed, I added extra rule that specifies iframe as a valid children of any container, and iframe can have all the necessary attributes it comes with
- Switching back and forth between Visual and Text editor (at least on my environment), saving progress on both Visual/Text while editing content on the other sides, autosaving/drafting/forcing it to close and using browser backups did not cause codes/attributes/iframe to disappear so far (before handing the project to the client and after my client reported the issue).
- I've tested with Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, and Opera on both iOS and Windows environment
- I asked my client what their work environment is like, and my client is using Mac, and according to my client, there is no browser extentions like adblock or script block installed on Firefox/Safari

This is what I added in the filter before my client even reported having the problem:

```
$opts = '*[*]';
$initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
$initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
```

I added extra and modified the rules since, and this is what I have right now (in functions.php):

```
$initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts. ',@[role|aria-hidden|aria-checked|aria-selected|aria-pressed|aria-label|aria-labelledby|aria-disabled|aria-grabbed|aria-controls|aria-describedby|aria-required|tabindex|class|style|data-tabs|data-tabs-content|data-equalizer|data-equalizer-watch|data-equalize-on|data-count|data-ratio|frameborder|allowFullScreen|allowfullscreen]';
$initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = 'iframe[title|class|type|width|height|src|frameborder|allowFullScreen|allowfullscreen|data-ratio]';
$initArray['valid_children'] = '+p[iframe],+div[iframe]';
$initArray['invalid_elements'] = '';
```

I added iframe as valid children, and specifically told TinyMCE that there are no invalid elements.

...And the client is still having the same problem and I need some insight on why this is happening and how to fix this.

Anyone had the similar experience or might have an answer to this issue?

Edit: Currently looking for a plugin-less solution. There is nothing wrong with using a plugin, I suppose, but if it's doable by writing extra bit of code to solve this, then I'd rather not use it.

Edit 2: It seems that iframe being removed is more pressing issue at the moment. Attributes seem to be intact from my client's grasp, for now.

Update: **Figured out the issue. It had nothing to do with TinyMCE.** One thing I neglected to account for was that the website is a multisite, and that admin account don't actually have 'unfiltered_html' capability. It was something I did not know, and now I know.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress cleans all the content edited in TinyMCE using KSES functions. So, even if you whitelist some tags in TinyMCE settings, on save, WordPress will filter the content using own KSES functions and will remove tags that are not allowed. By default, only administrators can use IFRAME in the content, for other users, it will be stripped on save. Here is the article on manipulating tags that KSES will allow to be used in content: [KSES Tricks](https://wp-mix.com/kses-tricks/). Using similar method, you can add IFRAME to allowed tags list for all users.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, but perhaps I should've clarified on few more details. My client does have privilege, and has not been saving the work. To my knowledge, KSES fires on save/update post? The client makes changes, realizes that iframe has disappeared, and leaves the page, only to leave autosave (which I can see from the revision history that iframe has been removed). Which is why I'm starting to believe that, this is less and less to do with TinyMCE or WordPress, rather it's something on my client's computer that is causing this.

Comment: You would need to debug the editing process: what is sent to the server, what is processed, and exactly when the IFRAME was removed. I am not aware of anything in the browser that does that, but it is possible that there is Chrome (or other browsers) extensions that can do that.

Comment: Oops, meant to say 'admin' privilege, but anyway, my client has claimed that there is no browser extension or plugins running and I'm not aware of any that may interfere with editing process either. How much I believe my client, I usually don't, but at this point I have to work with what I got. I will look further into any browser extensions/plugins that may cause this issue.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! Although your answer didn't solve the issue, because of you mentioning KSES and WordPress privilege level, I eventually figured out the issue.